# Rigorous argument for splitting a sum according to a random time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be some random variables and let $\tau_1, \tau_2, \tau_3$ be some interger-valued random variables such that $\tau_1 < \tau_2 < \tau_3$ almost surely. All these random variables are **not** assumed to be independent!

Now, consider the statement
$$ E \left[ \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_3}  X_k \right] = E \left[ \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2}  X_k 
 + \sum_{k=\tau_2 +1}^{\tau_3}  X_k \right] = E \left[ \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2}  X_k \right]
 +E \left[\sum_{k=\tau_2 +1}^{\tau_3}  X_k \right].$$

The first identity holds naturally. However, does the second identity hold as obviously? If the statement is correct, how could you rigorously show that it is indeed correct?

If the statement is incorrect, why and what would one need to assume about the random variables for this to be true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let ${F}$ be the sigma field generated by $\sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k$. By the tower rule it holds
$$E \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k + \sum_{k=\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3} X_k = E E (\sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k + \sum_{k=\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3} X_k |F) =
E \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k + EE (\sum_{k=\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3} X_k |F)=
\quad E \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k + E \sum_{k=\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3} X_k $$
In the second step it is used that $\sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k$ is F measurable.

Consequently the equality does hold

Edit (Thanks for your remark):

One can use the linearity of the expectation immediately.

$E(X+Y) = E(X) + E(Y)$ for $Y:= \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k, Y:= \sum_{k=\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3}X_k $. Linearity of the expectation is also implicitly used in my orignial answer.

Comment: Thanks. In the second equality you're also using that $E\big[ \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k + E [ \sum_{\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3} X_k \mid F]\big] = E\big[ \sum_{k=\tau_1}^{\tau_2} X_k\big] + E \big[ E [\sum_{\tau_2+1}^{\tau_3} X_k \mid F]\big]$. Is there no argument needed for this?

Comment: You are of course right, I did not actually touch on the question but instead just chose a more complicated version which implicitly still uses linearity of expectation.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. If I understand your edit correctly, you're saying that the statement in my post does not need a proper argument (except for the standard linearity property of the expectation)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am thinking

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. You could e.g. write the whole expression simply as a sum with the joint distribution $P(X_1, \dots, X_n, \tau_1, \tau_2, \tau_3 \in \cdot)$ and then it's quite obvious that linearity still works?! I guess?

Comment: Perhaps it is even more obvious to see if you the distribution of X and Y defined as above P(X, Y), in which the proof is just the proof of linearity of expectation